# Error in react-select 8 with react 16 and react-script 5

Tags: reactjs, react-select, react-scripts

I am not sure what is causing the issue, but it gives an error on react-select map function (screenshot attched).
react 16, react-scripts 5 and react-select 8
"react": "^16.14.0",
"react-aux": "^1.1.0",
"react-confirm-alert": "^2.0.5",
"react-datepicker": "^1.8.0",
"react-dom": "^16.4.1",
"react-draggable": "^4.4.4",
"react-fontawesome": "^1.6.1",
"react-idle-timer": "^4.6.4",
"react-portal": "^4.2.0",
"react-pro-sidebar": "^0.4.4",
"react-redux": "^5.0.7",
"react-router": "^4.3.1",
"react-router-dom": "5.3.3",
"react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
"react-select": "^5.7.7",
[image]

Thanks, in advance.

Comment: The screenshot provided doesn't contain full error details but I think you are trying to access some properties of a null or undefined value inside the map function. Please update the question with related code section and full error message.

Comment: The same code works well with react-scripts 4 but gives error when moved to react-scripts 5. We want to upgrade the react-script to keep latest version on.

Comment: Without any more details we can't confirm whether it's an issue with react-script or not. Update the question with a full error message and source code section that throws this error, probably the `buildCategorizedOptions` function.